# yield: why can't i write: p test_method { i.upcase }

Tags: ruby, yield

```
def test_method
  ["a", "b", "c"].map {|i| yield(i) }
end
```

If I call test_method like this:

```
p test_method {|i| i.upcase }
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
```

**Why do I need the {|i|} inside the block, instead of just saying this:**

```
p test_method { i.upcase }
```

**The reason I think so is because when yield is called in test_method, we already have an {|i|}**

```
  ["a", "b", "c"].map {|i| yield(i) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block needs a parameterized value to pass to the upcase method.  It can be looked at this way:  If you leave out the |i| in the block it has no way of "catching" the value yielded (i in test_method)

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from Groovy background where they have an implicit iterator, or even from Scala where you can do without this |i| using partial functions, then you might find it a logical question, however, at the current moment the best you can do in Ruby 1.9 or even inside Rails, is to use the Symbol#to_block method like JRL mentioned:

```
p test_method &:upcase
```

So just add the **&:** before the method name.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9 you can write:

```
 p test_method &:upcase
```

Answer (score 2):

As ennuikiller said, you must define what you wish to name the variable(s) that is passed back from the `yield` statement. This has to do with a variable's scope. The scope inside of the block that you pass to `test_method` does not know about the `i` variable. You can actually call this whatever you wish.

For instance, you could do the following:

```
def test_method
  ["a", "b", "c"].map { |i| yield(i) }
end

p test_method { |some_variable_name| some_variable_name.upcase }
```

Just because the test method knows about it, it does not means that the block that you pass to the test method will know about it.

**Edit 1:** To give a little more information, you can redefine `test_method` as follows if it makes it a little bit more clear:

```
def test_method(&block)
  if not block.nil?
    ["a", "b", "c"].map { |i| yield(i) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time you call

```
p test_method {|i| i.upcase}
```

The `|i|` used in the method definition is not visible (its scope is solely within the `{}`. 
In particular you are building a block that takes a single variable, and to build that block you must specify what that variable is. Note that

p test_method `{|j| j.upcase}`

is also valid.